# How can i insert location into mysql database in android

Tags: android

Hi im developing android app based on location. anyone know is it possible to record live location and insert into MySQL database, so whenever user search it should show the map where he or she went with real time. if anyone knows please give an example

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. You would need to listen for location changes through Android's `LocationManager` service.

One your app is registered as a listener to the service, you will be given periodical updates about the device's latitude and longitude position. These values are what you should persist in a database.

Obviously, your app would need to ask for a few permissions in order to enable GPS tracking. If you're interested in showing the points aswell, you also need to setup a `GoogleMap` and request an API key for it to work.

As an addition, Android do not natively support direct writing into a MySql database. Your best bet wpuld be to implement a REST API to act as a middle man between your app and the database (hosted online) and post a write request through said API.

Here's some useful links for you to get started:

- [Official docs for location strategy](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)
- [Official docs for LocationManager API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

***p.s.***, If my answer sounds too broad to you, it is because the thing you asked demands a broad anwer. Do some research and try to recreate an already existing example. Next time you're posting a question, try to narrow down to the very specific thing you'd want to know.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, i got it, and ill be alright next time when ask question and ill do the research about the location. (y)

Comment: No problem! Then again, everyone has to start somewhere. Good luck and have fun making your app!

Answer (score 1):

first you need to get current location location.getlatitude() ,location.getlongitude() then save in variable these variable pass the volley library just simple is that volley network method to save value in mysql database.
if you want to change value in database when user change location you should pass declare the method in locationChanged lisner.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to write into a MySQL database. You need to do a interface e.g. with an REST API.

The simplest way that will fit your need is to write some PHP files that are able to perform writes and reads from the database and POST/GET your data.

I found a pretty good example here:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: thanks you for your idea im good in those php mysql and Jason parser and im experience with those. but only think that i want to record live location which means whenever user go out it should record and save it in mysql database and when user search by date it should show with the map, if you have any example please